# postman-proxy-ca.crt file not showing up, even tho OpenSSL is installed

Tags: openssl, postman

I recently discovered the postman proxy as an useful tool to reverse engineer an API, but the API which I want to reverse engineer uses `https` and not just `http`, so I have to install a certificate, which I was trying to do using [this](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/capturing-http-requests/#capture-https-traffic-with-postmans-built-in-proxy) tutorial, which explains that you have to install OpenSSL, which I then did, I also set the system variable and the installation of OpenSSL worked, which I tested using

```
> openssl version
OpenSSL 3.0.0 7 sep 2021 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.0 7 sep 2021)
```

and I restarted the postman app.
Then I opened `%APPDATA%\Postman\proxy`, but there was only the `certificates` directory, in which the only file is `cert.json` which is just an empty json file, only containing `{}` .
Am I doing something wrong, or what is the problem with the `postman-proxy-ca.crt` file not showing up?

I am using windows 10 with OpenSSL 3.0.0 and the Postman app version 8.12.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem, it was because I installed OpenSSL 3.0, which came out eight days before I asked this, but it only works with OpenSSL 1.1.1, which is the other supported version of OpenSSL.
So the solution is to install the older version, 1.1.1.